# How to get android phone listed in device manager?

Tags: android, usb

I am unable to connect my nexus 4 with USB to my PC as media device. When I connect them the only thing that I can notice is that my phone is charging. I have tried to delete all useless drivers with USBdeview and even installed universal adb driver(http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver)  but still I couldn't get connected . And here is what my device manager looks like http://postimg.org/image/i7jmwdhiz/.

Comment: Have you enabled usb debugging in your device?

Comment: Yes I have enabled and I have tried both with and without ticking the option

Comment: I guess you have only enabled charging in your usb options, please check your usb settings.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't enable usb debugging in your device. Here's how to:

**First, you need to enable "Developer Options Menu".**

1. Click Menu button to enter into App drawer.
2. Go to "Settings"
3. Scroll
   down to the bottom and tap "About phone" or "About tablet"
4. Scroll down to the bottom of the "About phone" and locate the "Build
   Number" field.
5. Tap the Build number field seven times to enable Developer Options. Tap a few times and you'll see a countdown that reads "You are now 3 steps away from being a developer."
6. When you are done, you'll see the message "You are now a developer!".
7. Tap the Back button and you'll see the Developer options menu under System on your Settings screen.
   [image]

**Now, you can enable USB Debugging mode.**

Go to Settings>Developer Options>USB Debugging. Tap the USB Debugging checkbox.

PS: if your android version is lower then 4.2 then you will have "Developer options" or "Development" in settings

Comment: Actually I did it already anyways thanks for replying. Is there any other thing you would suggest me to try

Comment: Make sure OS can see the device, so it's not in "charge only" mode. I have a usb cable that connects my phone to PC, but OS cannot recognize it, so it's only charging, while other cables work fine.